# Excel: Sum all values in Column B for each ID in Column A, and create a new column with all these results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

So I don't know if I'm framing this correctly. I have a database with thousands of rows. Column A is a code that identifies a specific product, and Column B has a (0-no;1-yes) value. I need each row in Column C to have the sum of all values in Column B, for each specific product in Column A.

In the example below, there are three products, and Column C is how the output should look like. All rows with X in Column A sum the values Column B (only from said rows) and the result printed on all of the same rows in Column C. Every row with X (Column A) should have a 5 (Column C), which is the sum of all 1s in Column B (only on rows with an X).

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 5 |
| Y | 0 | 2 |
| Y | 1 | 2 |
| Z | 0 | 1 |
| X | 1 | 5 |
| X | 1 | 5 |
| Z | 1 | 1 |
| X | 1 | 5 |
| Z | 0 | 1 |
| X | 1 | 5 |
| X | 0 | 5 |
| Z | 0 | 1 |
| Y | 1 | 2 |

Keep in mind that there are thousands of products with different and complex IDs (Column A). I thought of creating a Dynamic Table that gives me the result (sum of B for said values) in a different sheet and then merging both based on Column A values, but I'm trying to do this in one single step with a code in Column C.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of doing this, perhaps for readability one can use the following formulas:

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, A2:B14, δ, TAKE(α,,1), HSTACK(α,SUMIFS(TAKE(α,,-1),δ,δ)))
```

---

Or Using `SUMIF()` may be:

```
=LET(α, A2:B14, δ, TAKE(α,,1), HSTACK(α,SUMIF(δ,δ,TAKE(α,,-1))))
```

---

With out returning the whole array and only for column `C`

```
=SUMIF(A2:A14,A2:A14,B2:B14)
```

---

Another alternative is to use `MMULT()`

```
=MMULT(N(A2:A14=TOROW(A2:A14)),B2:B14)
```

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula works on old Excels also:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF((A$2:A$14=A2)*(B$2:B$14=1),1,0))`

[image]